# Stop element from disappearing when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm writing a simple jQuery plugin that will dynamically place a div under a text box whenever it has focus. I've been able to get the position just about right in all the browsers.

I have to attach two event handlers as well on the `focus` and `blur` events of the textbox. And it works okay, but the problem is that the div that has been placed under the textbox  closes even when we click on it. Now it makes sense why it would so happen, it's because the textbox loses focus, but is there a way I can stop it from happening?

I tried attaching this to the blur event handler -

```
if($(mainElem).is(":focus")) return;
```

where `mainElem` is the div that is shown below the textbox.

Here is a [jsFiddle to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/9YHKW/) the problem.

Comment: Why are you using the blur function to hide it?

Comment: @putvande Because, I want it to be hidden when I the text box loses focus, what else can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to be able to use the `blur` event if you want to place "clickable" elements in the div that shows. One way to solve this is to bind your event listener to a more global element like the `document` and then filter out the targets.

Here is a code sample:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
      var targetEl = e.target,
          parent = $(e.target).parents()[0];
      if (relElem[0] === targetEl || self[0] === targetEl || self[0] === parent) {
          $(mainElem).show();
      } else {
          $(mainElem).hide();
      }
 });
```

Here is an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9YHKW/6/

Comment: This worked well even with multiple elements, but I'm not so satisified. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14863356/Droppie/Default.html) is the result. I added a functionality to show the droppie when the textbox has focus as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fiddle that I threw together for a project a while back: http://jsfiddle.net/MYcZx/4/

While it is not based off of your fiddle (and I do apologize) I believe that the functionality is much the same as what you're looking for. My example does not include input fields, but rather spans that hold the values. And while I'm not managing focus/blur, you could add a tabIndex attribute to the spans and then add a trigger on focus that would open the menu.

```
var $sub = $('.subscription');

$sub
    .on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();    
    })
    .on('click', 'li', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            $options = $parent.children('li'),
            $value = $parent.siblings('.value'),
            isMulti = $parent.hasClass('multi'),
            values = [];

        if(!isMulti) {
            $options.removeClass('active');            
        }

        $this.toggleClass('active');

        $options.filter('.active').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).text());
        });

        $value.text(values.join(', ') || 'select');

        $value[(values.length ? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class']('set');
    });

var $clone = $sub.clone(true);

$('.new')
    .on('click', function() {
        $(this).before($clone.clone(true));
    });
```