# How to stop fadeOut if focusout is on action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I pick one of the checkboxes, I want that checkboxcontainer should not fadeout. How can I achieve this?

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9YHKW/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".textbox").focus(function(){
    $(".checkboxcontainer").fadeIn('fast');
  });
  $('.checkbox').change(function(){
    $(".checkboxcontainer").show();
  });
  $(".textbox").focusout(function(){
    $(".checkboxcontainer").fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop element from disappearing when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197305/stop-element-from-disappearing-when-clicked)

Comment: So you want the input to fadeout? Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9YHKW/11/

Comment: @Kolby thank you, but not what I am searching. Adeneo has the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a stop :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".textbox").on({
        focus: function () {
            $(".checkboxcontainer").fadeIn('fast');
        },
        blur: function () {
            $(".checkboxcontainer").fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
    $('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
        $(".checkboxcontainer").stop(true, true).show();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9YHKW/12/)

You could also use a small timeout, and check what element has focus, then clear the timeout and reset focus etc.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var active, timer;
    $(".textbox").on({
        focus: function () {
            $(".checkboxcontainer").fadeIn('fast');
        },
        blur: function () {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $(".checkboxcontainer").fadeOut('fast');
            },300);
        }
    });
    $('.checkbox').on({
        mousedown: function() {
            active = document.activeElement;
        },
        change: function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            active.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9YHKW/14/)

Comment: That's what I was searching. Thank you!